# Running Tests From a Module

Tags: python, unit-testing, import, tdd, python-unittest

I am attempting to run some unit tests in python from what I believe is a module.  I have a directory structure like

```
TestSuite.py
UnitTests
  |__init__.py
  |TestConvertStringToNumber.py
```

In testsuite.py I have

```
import unittest

import UnitTests

class TestSuite:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

print "Starting testting"
suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromModule(UnitTests)
unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=1).run(suite)
```

Which looks to kick off the testing okay but it doesn't pick up any of the test in TestConvertNumberToString.py.  In that class I have a set of functions which start with 'test'.

What should I be doing such that running python TestSuite.py actually kicks off all of my tests in UnitTests?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is some code which will run all the unit tests in a directory:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import unittest
import sys
import os

unit_dir = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else '.'
os.chdir(unit_dir)
suite = unittest.TestSuite()
for filename in os.listdir('.'):
    if filename.endswith('.py') and filename.startswith('test_'):
        modname = filename[:-2]
        module = __import__(modname)
        suite.addTest(unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromModule(module))

unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

If you call it testsuite.py, then you would run it like this:

```
testsuite.py UnitTests
```

Comment: Beautiful, thanks.  It was the __import__ function I was missing

Answer (score 0):

Using Twisted's "trial" test runner, you can get rid of TestSuite.py, and just do:

```
$ trial UnitTests.TestConvertStringToNumber
```

on the command line; or, better yet, just

```
$ trial UnitTests
```

to discover and run all tests in the package.